# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a todos los campos de un archivo json en Typescript?

Tags: json, typescript

He intentado usar varios bucles for pero me da el siguiente error: 
error TS2339: Property 'elements' does not exist on type 'string'.
Elements es un campo del archivo json al que quiero acceder.

```
    for (let a of consultas) {
              for ( let b of a.elements){
                    for ( let c of b.steps) {
                       console.log(c.name);
                    }
               }
    }
```

El JSON tiene esta estructura:

```
[
    {
        "line": 11,
        "elements": [
            {
                "line": 28,
                "name": "API",
                "description": "",
                "id": "2",
                "type": "scenario",
                "keyword": "Scenario Outline",
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "result": {
                            "duration": 4429388190,
                            "status": "failed"
                        },
                        "keyword": "Given "
                    }
                ],
            }
        ],
        "name": "MI prueba",
        "description": " Pruebas de manejo ",
        "id": "api",
        "keyword": "Feature",
        "uri": "src"
    }
]
```

Comment: Bienvenido Marco, deberías mostrar que has intentado hasta ahora, no solo nombrarlo. Para que podamos ayudarte es necesario disponer de información clara y específica.

Comment: Te está diciendo que `b` es un string y no tiene ningún atributo `elements`

Comment: Exacto, busco la forma de que no me aparezca ese error y de lograr obtener los datos del json.

Comment: Muestra el JSON

Comment: [
  {
    "line": 11,
    "elements": [
      {
        "line": 28,
        "name": "API",
        "description": "",
        "id": "2",
        "type": "scenario",
        "keyword": "Scenario Outline",
        "steps": [
          {
            "result": {
               "duration": 4429388190,
              "status": "failed"
            },
            "keyword": "Given "
          }
        ],
      }],
    "name": "MI prueba",
    "description": "  Pruebas de manejo ",
    "id": "api",
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "uri": "src"
  }
]

Comment: Ese JSON es incompleto, ya que no está `artefacto`

Comment: Si es un problema de ts entonces cada elemento debe tener su tipo. Donde estan los tipos de a, b o c? Ts te protesta porque necesita saber especificamente el tipo de cada cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido que no me salga el error declarando:

```
   let b: any;
```